# Whats wrong with my code? Need To add String to shortcode?

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, urls

I need to add a string to a wordpress shortcode.. cannot get it to work...

```
    <?php
$special_id = ' . do_shortcode('[url_path_number]')' ;
echo do_shortcode('[user_meta key="_wc_social_login_profile_image" id="'.$special_id.'"]');

?>
```

The end result is suppose to be a url addresss.

Answer (score 1):

```
$special_id = ' . do_shortcode('[url_path_number]')' ;
```

Is completely wrong. `do_shortcode()` is a function and shouldn't be inside quotes, because that just makes a string that says "do_shortcode()". I don't even know what you're trying to do with the dot at the beginning.

```
$special_id = do_shortcode('[url_path_number]');
```

Is correct.